# Improving ggplot Heatmap Expressiveness with Extreme Outliers in Parameter Estimation Matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, heatmap

I'm creating a heatmap from a matrix that includes some extreme outliers along with other values that have minimal variation. Here's my current approach:

```
set.seed(123)
parameters_tot <- matrix(rnorm(1000000), nrow = 1000)
num_outliers <- 10  
outlier_values <- rnorm(num_outliers, mean = 50, sd = 5)  
outlier_positions <- matrix(sample(1:1000000, num_outliers), ncol = 1)
parameters_tot[outlier_positions] <- outlier_values

parameters_df_enet <- as.data.frame(parameters_tot)
parameters_df_enet$row <- 1:nrow(parameters_df_enet)
parameters_df_long <- gather(parameters_df_enet, key = "column", value = "value", -row)
heatmap_enet = ggplot(parameters_df_long, aes(x = column, y = row, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +  # Change the color gradient as needed
  labs(title = "Heatmap of Parameter Estimation Values", x = "Columns", y = "Rows")
```

However, the resulting heatmap doesn't exhibit distinct colors due to the presence of extreme outliers. How can I enhance the expressiveness of the heatmap while still incorporating these outliers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use some of the same approaches you’d use to handle outliers in other situations, such as winsorizing or log transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a log transformation:

```
parameters_df_long$value_log <- log1p(parameters_df_long$value)

heatmap_enet <-  ggplot(parameters_df_long, aes(x = column, y = row, fill = value_log)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
  labs(title = "Heatmap of Parameter Estimation Values (Log)", x = "Columns", y = "Rows")
```

In your example we see different colors after having applied log transformation.